# What is the font used for "320" in the logo 320 RiverBar at Westin Chicago River North

Tags: font-identification

I am trying to identify the font used for "320" in the logo 320 RiverBar at the Westin Chicago River North. I tried searching for the font using WhatTheFont and the best I could find was some variation of Didot.

Original Logo

[image: 320 Logo]

The font "Didot-HTF-B06-Bold" is pretty close. I am a little confused because I cannot find a licensed version of this font.

[image: Didot-HTF-B06-Bold]

The Director of Sales and Marketing there wasn't much help.

Comment: That green outline?

Comment: The green outline is Didot-HTF-B06-Bold overlaid on the original logo to show the difference.

Comment: okay, but this font is even more close match for digit 3 https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/paratype/diet-didot/ I think you linked it before. Check the Dietdidot Title font

Comment: And remaining digits are possibly modified, because I feel they took inspiration from Georgia font 320 (it has smaller 2 and 0) :D But modifying would also be a big challenge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didot-HTF is the Didot font family from [Hoefler & Co](https://typography.com). (HTF is their old name, Hoefler Type Foundry.) There are different versions of the family for different text sizes ("optical sizes"), so it's possible the slight differences are due to the font used for the image being a different optical size.

Answer (score 0):

The closest font I could find was "Didot-HTF-M11-Medium" or some variation of that type of font family. I think I will adjust the text manually and call it a day.

[image: Didot vs logo]